# My Parser Skips Elements

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make an RSS reader that uses an XML from the web. For some reason it only reads the last element.

This is pretty much the XML file:

```
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <item>
            <mainTitle>...</mainTitle>
            <headline>
                <title>...</title>
                <description>...</description>
                <subTitle>...</subTitle>
                <link>...</link>
            </headline>

            <headline>
                <title>...</title>
                <description>...</description>
                <subTitle>...</subTitle>
                <link>...</link>
            </headline>
        </item>

        <item>
            <mainTitle>...</mainTitle>
            <headline>
                <title>...</title>
                <description>...</description>
                <subTitle>...</subTitle>
                <link>...</link>
            </headline>

            <headline>
                <title>...</title>
                <description>...</description>
                <subTitle>...</subTitle>
                <link>...</link>
            </headline>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

This is the parser:

```java
public class RssHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    // Feed and Article objects to use for temporary storage
    private Article currentArticle = new Article();
    private List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();

    // Number of articles added so far
    private int articlesAdded = 0;

    // Number of articles to download
    private static final int ARTICLES_LIMIT = 20;

    // Current characters being accumulated
    StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();

    // Current characters being accumulated
    int cap = new StringBuffer().capacity();

    // Basic Booleans
    private boolean wantedItem = false;
    private boolean wantedHeadline = false;
    private boolean wantedTitle = false;

    public List<Article> getArticleList() {
        return articleList;
    }

    public Article getParsedData() {
        return this.currentArticle;
    }

    public RssHandler() {
        this.currentArticle = new Article();
    }

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes atts) {
        chars = new StringBuffer();

    }

    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {

        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
            currentArticle.setTitle(chars.toString());
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("subtitle")) {
            currentArticle.setDescription(chars.toString());
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubdate")) {
            currentArticle.setPubDate(chars.toString());
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("guid")) {
            currentArticle.setGuid(chars.toString());
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("author")) {
            currentArticle.setAuthor(chars.toString());
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
            currentArticle.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) 

        // Check if looking for article, and if article is complete
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

            articleList.add(currentArticle);

            currentArticle = new Article();

            // Lets check if we've hit our limit on number of articles
            articlesAdded++;
            if (articlesAdded >= ARTICLES_LIMIT) {
                throw new SAXException();
            }
        }
        chars.setLength(0);
    }
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        chars.append(ch, start, length);

    }
}
```

Whenever I debug the application qName is never a direct child of Item.

It reads rss -> channel -> item -> title -> description ...

I'm clueless. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) At the end of endElement() method, you are not resetting the chars length i.e

```
   public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {

    //...           
    //Reset 'chars' length at the end always.
    chars.setLength(0);
    }
```

2) Change your characters(...) method like below:

```
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
        chars.append(ch, start, length);
    }
```

[EDIT

3) Move initialization of 'chars' from 'startElement' to constructor. i.e:

```
public RssHandler() {
    this.currentArticle = new Article();
    //Add here..
    chars = new StringBuffer();
}
```

and,

```
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes atts) {
    //Remove below line..
    //chars = new StringBuffer();
}
```

4) Finally, use qName to check matching tags instead of localName i.e

```
    if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
        currentArticle.setTitle(chars.toString().trim());
    } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("subtitle")) {
        currentArticle.setDescription(chars.toString().trim());
    } //...
```

EDIT]

More info @ [Using SAXParser in Android](http://chandan-tech.blogspot.in/2010/08/parsing-xml-document-using-androids.html)

Comment: Thank you! I changed that, but the main problem still persists, since it doesn't recognize the <headline> tag, it only posts the last article from each <item>. It rewrites every title/subtitle/pubdate etc with the last one (in this case the last headline).

Comment: Please check edited answer where missed out fixes have been applied